# How do I get my HTML5 Location result in a global variable?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geen geolocatie hier.";
    }

function showPosition(position) {
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lon = position.coords.longitude;
var total = String(lat).concat(',', String(lon));
}
```

How do I get that last 'total'-variable to be usable in other functions? And why doesn't declaring a global variable in the showPosition() function seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `var` before it, it will be global then. Alternatively you can use `window.total = ...`, but it's only semantic change.

Comment: I tried that. When I try to reference it after it shows up as 'undefined'.

Comment: Impossible. You simply don't understand that javascript is async. You are probably trying to read it before it was received.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If you move the var decloration out of the scope of the function, it will be global.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var total;

function getLocation() {...}

function showPosition(position) {
    ...
    total = String(lat).concat(',', String(lon));
     ...
}

// I can access total from out here
```